# Help wiring a smart light switch-one neutral for multiple lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, light, smart-switch

I have 4-5 outdoor lights and two porch lights which are all on the same circuit.

In the switch box there is only one hot, one neutral, and one ground (split).

There are two light switches. One controls the outdoor lights. One controls the two porch lights. The outdoor lights are wired to a smart switch.

This is how they are originally wired. Neutral into smart switch. Two black “hot” into smart switch. One carries power (verified with a non contact voltage tester) one carries the load. Ground into the smart switch.

For the two porch lights. Both hot/power connected to the light switch. Both are hot as verified with the tester. The same ground split from the wall into ground.

Can I add a smart switch to control the two porch lights?

Would I wire both of the black wires into the live/load? Use a nut wire connector and connect the smart switch neutral to neutral? I would have two neutrals going to the same place. And ground to ground.

I am not sure if I am use both of the black wires into the live/load of the smart switch or if I have to make another two wires and those have two smart switches.

https://ibb.co/Kzw0BBZ

Comment: That switch sounds like it is in a switch loop.  The white is a hot/switched hot and there is no neutral in that box.  Neutral must be white, white does not need to be neutral.  Is the white connected to the switch?  Neutrals are not suppose to be switched.

Comment: A picture would help a **lot**. It is not clear how many cables you actually have, etc.

Comment: There is four I think. Two Hot, one for each light switch. one Ground. One Neutral. It seems multiple cables from the switches are connected to ground or neutral with a wire nut connector

Comment: https://ibb.co/Kzw0BBZ